# Find the term...

Tags: terminology

How do I get the number of possibilities  by the length of these 'blocks'? The smallest block has to have a minimum of 2 numbers.


[image]

What I already observed is, that it's always + (n-4)...

Example:

4 : 2 
+ (5-4) 
5 : 3 
+ (6-4) 
6 : 5

At the moment I don't even know how to start...

**EDIT**
[image]

Are there anymore options here?

Comment: You haven't given the rule for how to construct the blocks, so there cannot be a certain answer.  $2,3,5$ makes me think of Fibonacci numbers.  Are they [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) by parts greater than $1$?

Comment: @RossMillikan The blocks can be created as you wish, except that the smallest one has to be a minimum of 2 numbers...

Comment: You should have said that in the question.  Please edit it in so people don't have to read the comments to find out.

Comment: @RossMillikan I just updated my questions with another picture... Shouldn't it be 13 not 12 options?

Comment: @RossMillikan $3,2,3$ is the 3rd one... I also think that when you set 8 in the Fibonacci function, you get 21. (wrote this on my smartphone...)

Comment: It is 4,4 that is missing.  It would be *much* easier if you represent these as numbers instead of colored blocks.  Yes, next is 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the [Fibonacci numbers](https://oeis.org/A000045).  One of the comments in the OEIS entry is that $F(n)$ is the number of compositions of $n+1$ with no part equal to $1.$  To justify it, note that an acceptable composition of length $n$ can either be an acceptable composition of length $n+1$ with the last element lengthened by $1$, or an acceptable composition of length $n+2$ with a $2$ added at the end.  This gives the Fibonacci recurrence and doing a couple base cases by hand shows the offset.